# Have i built my servlet right?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web-applications

I have developed an web applcation (WebApplication 1) which has 1 servlet and many JSPs and this app has a certain fuctionality (lets say No1). 
In that application, inside the `processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`  method of the servlet, there are many `if else` statements in order to detect what the user wants to do.

**Servlet**

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException{

        init();        
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String jspAction = request.getParameter("action");

        if(jspAction.equals("home")){ 

            //do sth

            RequestDispatcher disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
            disp.forward(request, response);

        }else if(jspAction.equals("out")){ 

            //do sth

            RequestDispatcher disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/out.jsp");
            disp.forward(request, response);

        }//etc..

   }
}
```

In the JSPs links or a form submit have this link format `MyServlet?action=out`. Following this approach I have at this point 25  if statements.

So my question is this: Is this the right aproach to build my application or should I create different servlets for each function I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While that's a valid (and very basic) solution, it's better to use a MVC framework for that purose, than to reinvent the wheel. A central servlet as an access point to the application is a common practice and can for example be found in the early [Java EE design patterns](http://corej2eepatterns.com/), as **"front controller"** and **"dispatcher view"**.

You should have a look at Spring MVC, or Struts 2, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `java.util.HashMap<String, String>` to configure your navigation rules. Map key is action parameter value, and Map value is jsp page.

This way you could do the following

```
HashMap<String, String> navigationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
navigationMap.put("home", "/home.jsp");
navigationMap.put("out", "/out.jsp");
...
String jspAction = request.getParameter("action");
String page = navigationMap.get(jspAction);
RequestDispatcher disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(page);
...
```

This would solve your problem with big if-else, but if you want to do some actions for each navigationRule, you will have to use a more complicated Map to Map an Action Object that process request and return page.

This is some way what MVC framework like Structs or JSF does, Why don't you try an MVC framework?